# Possible typos in Adams' Lectures on Lie Groups

Tags: lie-groups

In his proof of Lemma 5.39, that if $\theta_r$ is a simple root then $\phi_r$ permutes the positive roots except $\theta_r$, which goes to $-\theta_r$, I don't quite follow his second proof. He claims that since $\phi_r(\theta_t)$ has at least one positive coefficients for simple root basis, it is a positive root. But I thought a positive root needs all its coefficients with respect  to a basis of simple roots nonnegative?

Comment: The simple roots are not just any basis.  They are (by definition) a basis that, given any root, either all its coefficients (in terms of the simple root basis) are positive, or all its coefficients are negative.  Therefore, one coefficient being positive implies all the other ones are.

Comment: Thanks! I learned the definition of simple roots as a set of positive roots which are indecomposable by other positive roots. Does that imply immediately what you suggested? Could you give a reference for the equivalence of the two notions?